# Is websocket client means ws://...index.html or using http://...index.html is ok with implementing websockets

Tags: java, websocket

I have created a websocket restful url like

```
ws://localhost:8080/wsserver/getPrice
```

and used a index.html page that consumes it as

```
socket = new Socket (url);
```

When i run the client i am able to get the price as per requirement.But what bothers me is that i have like

```
http://localhost:8080/goldBuying/index.html
```

as my page.
But i want that like

```
ws://localhost:8080/goldBuying/index.html
```

because i think that is only complete websocket implementation as client.

How to achieve that or what i have done is only possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Websockets are used for bidirectional data transfer between client and server. HTML files are used for displaying digital documents. These are two different things.

So, no, you can't use something like `ws://localhost:8080/goldBuying/index.html`, the `ws://` protocol always defines a server that receives or sends data.

Comment: Thanks Jakob. So what i  have implemented seems correct?

Comment: As far as I can tell from your code snippets, I would say that yes, it seems correct.